# Would it be useful to consoldate all the answers and comments about snakebite into a definitive answer?

Tags: discussion

There have been a number of questions about how to treat snakebite over the years.  The latest one to appear is an oldie -- [What should you do if you are bitten by a rattlesnake?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/376/what-should-you-do-if-you-are-bitten-by-a-rattlesnake) -- and one of the answers recommends [The Sawyer Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AU9PEC), which I never heard of until now.  (Should I buy one before spring?)  Also, prominent underneath the question is this comment:

> The answer is the same for pit vipers, which include rattlesnakes,
>   copperheads, and water moccasins. Bites from these snakes are usually
>   not fatal even without medical attention, and in most (or many?) cases
>   they don't use antivenin because the side effects might be worse than
>   a minor snakebite. Also, sometimes pit vipers bite without injecting
>   much or any venom. (This leads to some invalid claims of being immune
>   to snakebites.)

Would it be useful to write an authoritative answer, which would be a synthesis of the best of the old answers and would also specifically address misconceptions and/or erroneous information, and link to the other questions?  I know I am proposing quite a bit of work for someone -- it should probably be a collaborative effort among two or three people -- but I think it would be a valuable contribution.

Comment: How would you want to do it? There is so much (unbacked) controversy there, that anything "authoritative" would have to be backed up by a really strong set of sources. And even there I would suspect (I do not know the field) that the topic is not clearcut. E.g. the mentioned kit: AFAIK this is a horrible idea in that the damage done is pretty big and the success rate (if any) way too low - I am positive that you find backup for both views. So a simple rewrite/synthesis of existing answers would IMO be pretty pointless.

Comment: I didn't look at the kit in question and just assumed it is another one of those slice a huge area open and then suck. It seems this one only applies a vacuum. Seems like a hoax to me, but at least not very dangerous...

Comment: I think this a parcial solution to the problem http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/883/could-we-get-something-like-the-worldbuilding-hard-science-tag

Comment: I have not looked at them, but are any of the questions duplicates? If not what makes them different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is probably:  If the OP thinks it is a good idea, why doesn't the OP take a whack at it and post a draft on Meta for users to comment on?  And the answer to *that* is if we get a major snowstorm which keeps me housebound for several days, but *with* power, I probably will.

Like many "good ideas", this one probably wasn't.